# Google ads api for keywordideas in CURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, google-ads-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-script

I try to make a keyword searches system for our employ and i have google ads developer token
But I cannot able to find any CURL or PHP CURL setup guide.

Two reference links
[Ad API Examples](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/examples)

 [Method: customers.generateKeywordIdeas](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v11/customers/generateKeywordIdeas)

**An example from Google's documentation:**

```
curl -f --request POST "https://googleads.googleapis.com/v${API_VERSION}/customers/${CUSTOMER_ID}/campaignBudgets:mutate" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "developer-token: ${DEVELOPER_TOKEN}" \
--header "login-customer-id: ${MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID}" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
--data "{
'operations': [
  {
    'create': {
      'name': 'My Campaign Budget #${RANDOM}',
      'amountMicros': 500000,
    }
  },
  {
    'create': {
      'name': 'My Campaign Budget #${RANDOM}',
      'amountMicros': 500000,
    }
  }
]
}"
```

I try this code but got Error

```
    <?
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v11/customers/(MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID):generateKeywordIdeas');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\n\"keywordSeed\": {\n    \"keywords\": [\n    \"cofee\"\n  ]\n  }\n}");
    
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Login-Customer-Id: (MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID)';
    $headers[] = 'Developer-Token: DEVELOPER_TOKEN';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer (OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN)';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    print_r($result);
    curl_close($ch);
```

**I'm not getting any output**

Comment: What error did you get? any reason you dont want to use the php client library?

Comment: Without errors showed we can't help you...

Comment: now issue is solved

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v9/customers/generateKeywordIdeas 

Please tell us who i can pass country in {"geoTargetConstants":[],"keywordSeed":{"keywords":["seo"]} ,"language": string}

Please tell us how I can put the country in geoTargetConstants and language 

I try to download https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting .csv 

but I cannot able to find any example of how to implement geoTargetConstants and language

Answer (score 0):

This example is based on [Method: customers.generateKeywordIdeas](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v11/customers/generateKeywordIdeas)

**Try this:**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v11/customers/${CUSTOMER_ID}:generateKeywordIdeas');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'developer-token' => '${DEVELOPER_TOKEN}',
    'login-customer-id' => '${MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID}',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ${OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN}',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "geoTargetConstants": [ string ], "language": string, "keywordSeed": {object (KeywordSeed)},}');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

[LINK: Handy curl conversion tool](https://curlconverter.com/php/)

This is the curl code I used in the conversion tool to generate the PHP:

```
curl --request POST "https://googleads.googleapis.com/v11/customers/${CUSTOMER_ID}:generateKeywordIdeas" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "developer-token: ${DEVELOPER_TOKEN}" \
--header "login-customer-id: ${MANAGER_CUSTOMER_ID}" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
-d '{ "geoTargetConstants": [ string ], "language": string, "keywordSeed": {object (KeywordSeed)},}'
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v9/customers/generateKeywordIdeas 

Please tell us who i can pass country in {"geoTargetConstants":[],"keywordSeed":{"keywords":["seo"]} ,"language": string}

Please tell us how I can put the country in geoTargetConstants and language 

I try to download https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting .csv 

but I cannot able to find any example of how to implement geoTargetConstants and language

Comment: I updated the PHP curl in my answer.  Google does not make it easy.  I spent hours working on this.

Comment: Can you please tell me an example of any keyword with a US location with English language